# Numpy reshape function. How are these two lines of code different?

Tags: python, numpy

How are these two lines of codes different:

```
X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T

X_flatten = X.reshape(-1, X.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

these two lines have different outputs which are **not related** to each other
look at this example:
suppose `X` is like the following:

```
>>> X = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> X
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

first line output:

```
>>> X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T
>>> X_flatten
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

and the second line output is:

```
>>> X_flatten = X.reshape(-1, X.shape[0])
>>> X_flatten
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```